# Swift: Trying to print an empty string – The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation

Tags: swift, ios8

I have a model with a column `entry`, which is a `String`. Sometimes entry has some text in it, sometimes it doesn't and it's an empty string.

When I try to print the string in console, I'm getting `The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.` (running `e object.entry`)

Not sure why it isn't just printing `""`

Trying `e object.entry!` gives me `error: operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'String'`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Empty String "" doesn't mean nil, and `entry` is not an optional type.
I think you are supposed to declare  `entry` as "" when initialize the object

```
class object {
     var entry = ""
     //do anything you want next
}
```

Comment: It's interesting, I did another test, I set a breakpoint after the user hits "save" after using the UITextField and when I do `p textField.text`, I get `""` but when I do `e textField.text == ""`, I get `malloc: *** error for object 0x10464c7f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.` Theoretically it should be saving `""` when the user doesn't enter anything

Comment: the property `text` is an optional type, does it work if add an `!` after it? @ZackShapiro